# Finding elements in a numpy array with multiple criteria

Tags: numpy, python-3.x

How can i find the indices of elements in a Numpy array which satisfy multiple criteria?

Example: The function `numpy.nonzero` lets me find the indices according to some criterion:

```
In [1]: from numpy import *
In [2]: a = array([1,0,1,-1])
In [5]: nonzero(a != 0)
Out[5]: (array([0, 2, 3]),)
```

However, giving multiple criteria like this does not work:

```
In [6]: nonzero((a != 0) and (a < 0))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/cls/<ipython-input-6-85fafffc5d1c> in <module>()
----> 1 nonzero((a != 0) and (a < 0))

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

In MATLAB, it's possible to write:

```
find((d != 0) & (d < 0))
```

How can I do this with Numpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `&` instead of `and`:

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> a = array([1,0,1,-1])
>>> nonzero(a!=0)
(array([0, 2, 3]),)
>>> nonzero((a != 0) and (a < 0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>> nonzero((a != 0) & (a < 0))
(array([3]),)
>>> where((a != 0) & (a < 0))
(array([3]),)
```

Comment: Thanks. What does "IIUC" mean?